# How to change shared preferences on Android without running my app (like Settings bundle on iOS)?

Tags: android, application-settings, settings.bundle

I'm porting an iOS app over to Android. The iOS version creates a settings bundle, so the app's settings are shown as a sub section inside Apple's Settings app on the iPhone. This allows me to alter certain app preferences without actually running my app. Amongst others, I am able to add a "reset" switch in there that will be the first thing that gets inspected if my app starts. If it is set, all app settings will be reset to defaults.

Android also has a settings app - is there a way to get something similar to the iOS feature on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such thing on Android.
The settings should be in the app.

However, there is a "Clear data" button in device settings, so you don't have to implement the "reset" button yourself.